# check if the characters of a string can be rearranged to make a palindrome

Tags: java, algorithm, palindrome

I am working on a problem from codesignal, which asks to determine whether the characters of a string can be rearranged to make a palindrome. My approach to this was creating a `HashMap` and placing each character of the string in it. If the `HashMap` contains an even sum of all the values, we must make sure each value itself is even. Otherwise, if the sum is odd, we need to see if one value at most was not even. I am currently passing 9/10 tests.

The test I am failing has the input: `"aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaabbbccccaaaaaaaaaaaaa"`. My solution outputs `true` when it should be `false`. I do not see where I am messing up.

```
boolean palindromeRearranging(String inputString) {
    
    HashMap<Character,Integer> letters=new HashMap<Character,Integer>();
    boolean isPalidrome=false;
    
    //one character strings are palindromes
    if(inputString.length()==1)
    {
        isPalidrome=true;
    }

    //look at the string and count the instances of each character
    for(int i=0;i<inputString.length();i++)
    {
        //add each character not in the hashmap already
        if(!letters.containsKey(inputString.charAt(i)))
        {
            letters.put(inputString.charAt(i), 1);
        }
        //otherwise, increment the count
        else if(letters.containsKey(inputString.charAt(i)))
        {
            letters.put(inputString.charAt(i), letters.get(inputString.charAt(i)) + 1);
        }
    }
    
    //sum the values in the hashmap
    int sum=0;
    Collection<Integer>val=letters.values();
    //count of values that are not even
    int v=0;
    
    for(int n:val)
    {
        //System.out.println("n:"+n);
        sum+=n;
        
        //if a value corresponding to a key isn't even, increase the count 
        if(sum%2!=0)
        {
            v++;
        }
    }
    
    //System.out.println(sum);
    
    //if we have an even sum then we have to make sure each key has an even value
    if(sum%2==0)
    {
        for(int n:val)
        {
            //if a key doesn't have an even value
            if(n%2!=0)
            {
                isPalidrome=false;
            }
            else
                isPalidrome=true;
        }
    }
    
    if(sum%2!=0)
    {
        if(v==1)
        {
            isPalidrome=true;
        }
        else
            isPalidrome=false;
    }
    
    return isPalidrome;

}
```

Comment: You should use a debugger and step through your code. Look at all the values step by step.

Comment: That's usually my go-to choice but the debugger isn't available in CodeSignal's coding environment.

Comment: You don't need a debugger there. You have your code and you know the tested value, so use your own debugger

Comment: I'm not sure but your solution seems to be overly complicated, and probably the following method can do in a more simple manner: `final Collection<Character> pairs = new HashSet<>(); for ( int i = 0; i < cs.length(); i++ ) { final char ch = cs.charAt(i); if ( pairs.contains(ch) ) { pairs.remove(ch); } else { pairs.add(ch); } } return pairs.size() <= 1;`

Answer (score 1):

You forget to add break in loop inside `if(sum%2==0)`

```
boolean palindromeRearranging(String inputString) {

    HashMap<Character,Integer> letters=new HashMap<Character,Integer>();
    boolean isPalidrome=false;
    
    //one character strings are palindromes
    if(inputString.length()==1)
    {
        isPalidrome=true;
    }

    //look at the string and count the instances of each character
    for(int i=0;i<inputString.length();i++)
    {
        //add each character not in the hashmap already
        if(!letters.containsKey(inputString.charAt(i)))
        {
            letters.put(inputString.charAt(i), 1);
        }
        //otherwise, increment the count
        else if(letters.containsKey(inputString.charAt(i)))
        {
            letters.put(inputString.charAt(i), letters.get(inputString.charAt(i)) + 1);
        }
    }
    
    //sum the values in the hashmap
    int sum=0;
    Collection<Integer>val=letters.values();
    //count of values that are not even
    int v=0;
    
    for(int n:val)
    {
        //System.out.println("n:"+n);
        sum+=n;
        
        //if a value corresponding to a key isn't even, increase the count 
        if(n%2!=0)
        {
            v++;
        }
    }
    
    //System.out.println(sum);
    
    //if we have an even sum then we have to make sure each key has an even value
    if(sum%2==0)
    {
        for(int n:val)
        {
            //if a key doesn't have an even value
            if(n%2!=0)
            {
                isPalidrome=false;
                break;
            }
            else
                isPalidrome=true;
        }
    }
    
    if(sum%2!=0)
    {
        if(v==1)
        {
            isPalidrome=true;
        }
        else
            isPalidrome=false;
    }
    
    return isPalidrome;

}
```

Comment: I got your point. I modified my answer. But I also know there is implementation where `sum` is not needed and extra loop is not required.

Comment: This and the fix pointed out by Ehsan Gerayli fixed my problem.

Answer (score 1):

In this part of your code

```
if(sum%2!=0)
    {
        v++;
    }
```

it should change to

```
if(n%2!=0)
    {
        v++;
    }
```

Comment: This and the fix pointed out by amar_1995 fixed my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of calculating the sum of the hashmap values, below is my logic. Basically a palindrome can be formed with atmost one set of odd characters and can have any set of even characters. Lets say there is a string **aaaabbccc**. Here there are two sets of even characters(a & b) and one set of odd which can be a palindrome, if rearranged. Below is my program in c++.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
        string input;
        cin>> input;
        
        cout<< input<< endl;
        
        int a[26] = {0};

        for (int i = 0; input[i] != '\0'; i++)
            a[input[i] - 97]++;
        
        int odd = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++)
        {
            if (a[i] != 0)
            {
                if (a[i] % 2)
                {
                    odd++;
                    if (odd > 1)
                    {
                        cout<< "false"<< endl;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                
            }
        }

        if (odd < 2)
            cout<< "true"<< endl;
    return 0;
}
```

You can try this logic to check for a palindrome.

Answer (score 0):

```
 boolean solution(String str) {
        HashMap<String ,Integer> map=new HashMap<>();
        int count=0;
        int count1=0;
        for(String w:str.split("")){
            if(!map.containsKey(w)){
                map.put(w, 1);
            }
            else if(map.containsKey(w)){
                map.put(w, map.get(w)+1) ;}
        }
        boolean bool=false;
        for(Integer w: map.values()){
            if(w==1){
                count++;}
            else if(w%2==0){
                bool=true;}
            else if(w%2!=0){
                count1++;}
            bool=count>1||count1>1?false:true;
        }
        return bool;
    }
```

Comment: I did it with mapping Characters as Strings . every String has an Integer value to as counting number of each Characters. I did 2 counter one is counting characters that are exist just 1 time. if there is one char with 1 usage its ok but if if its more than one we should return false. I also checked count of characters used as odd number. if there are odd values of chars more than 1 it should also return false.